# How do I get a text output from a string created from an array to remain unshortened?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, text

Python/Numpy Problem. Final year Physics undergrad... I have a small piece of code that creates an array (essentially an n×n matrix) from a formula. I reshape the array to a single column of values, create a string from that, format it to remove extraneous brackets etc, then output the result to a text file saved in the user's Documents directory, which is then used by another piece of software. The trouble is above a certain value for "n" the output gives me only the first and last three values, with "...," in between. I think that Python is automatically abridging the final result to save time and resources, but I need all those values in the final text file, regardless of how long it takes to process, and I can't for the life of me find how to stop it doing it. Relevant code copied beneath...

```
import numpy as np; import os.path ; import os

'''
Create a single column matrix in text format from Gaussian Eqn.
'''

save_path = os.path.join(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"),"Documents")
name_of_file = 'outputfile' #<---- change this as required.
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt") 

matsize = 32

def gaussf(x,y): #defining gaussian but can be any f(x,y)
pisig = 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * matsize) #first term
sumxy = (-(x**2 + y**2)) #sum of squares term
expden = (2 * (matsize/1.0)**2) # 2 sigma squared
expn = pisig * np.exp(sumxy/expden) # and put it all together
return expn

matrix = [[ gaussf(x,y) ]\
for x in range(-matsize/2, matsize/2)\
for y in range(-matsize/2, matsize/2)] 

zmatrix = np.reshape(matrix, (matsize*matsize, 1))column

string2 = (str(zmatrix).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(' ', ''))

zbfile = open(completeName, "w")
zbfile.write(string2)
zbfile.close()

print completeName
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(completeName)) 
print num_lines
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should iterate over the array/list if you just want to write the contents.

```
zmatrix = np.reshape(matrix, (matsize*matsize, 1))


with open(completeName, "w") as zbfile: # with closes your files automatically
    for row in zmatrix:
        zbfile.writelines(map(str, row))
        zbfile.write("\n")
```

Output:

```
0.00970926751178
0.00985735189176
0.00999792646484
0.0101306077521
0.0102550302672
0.0103708481917
0.010477736974
0.010575394844
0.0106635442315
.........................
```

But using `numpy` we simply need to use [tofile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html):

```
zmatrix = np.reshape(matrix, (matsize*matsize, 1))
 
# pass sep  or you will get binary output
zmatrix.tofile(completeName,sep="\n")
```

Output is in the same format as above.

Calling `str` on the matrix will give you similarly formatted output to what you get when you try to `print` so that is what you are writing to the file the formatted truncated  output.

Considering you are using python2, using `xrange`  would be more efficient that using rane which creates a list, also having multiple imports separated by colons is not recommended, you can simply:

`import numpy as np, os.path, os`

Also variables and function names should use underscores  `z_matrix`,`zb_file`,`complete_name` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to fiddle with the string representations of `numpy` arrays. One way is to use `tofile`:

```
zmatrix.tofile('output.txt', sep='\n')
```

Comment: Ahh.. too slow. You're right of course. I think `tofile` is even better than iterating row-wise.

Comment: I just wanted to show how to  iterate over an array/list and write each row and also how to use with.

Comment: I was not aware of that limitation to "str"; my Python coding experience up to this point has been in very much smaller realms. I shall plumb that in after lunch. Many thanks to you both!

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! It's outputting correctly now.